# How to use discriminated unions with classes

Tags: typescript, serialization, discriminated-union

I'm trying to convert a discriminated union into a string. The discriminated union consists of two interfaces. If I call the function with a simple object that matches the one of the interfaces, I get the expected result. If I call the function with a class the *implements* the interface, I get `undefined` back. Can you explain this behavior to me? An is there any way around this?

```js
interface Foo {
    kind: 'pending',
    myVar: string
}

interface Bar {
    kind: 'running',
    myVar2: string
}

type FooBarUnion = Foo|Bar;

class FooClass implements Foo {
    kind: 'pending'
    myVar: string

    constructor(text) {
        this.myVar = text;
    }
}

function fbuToString(o: FooBarUnion ) {
    switch (o.kind) {
        case "pending": return `O is pending. ${o.myVar}`;
        case "running": return `O is running. ${o.myVar2}`;
    }
}

// prints undefined
console.log(fbuToString(new FooClass('test')));

// prints expected result
console.log(fbuToString({kind:'pending', myVar: 'test'}));
```

I'm running this file with `ts-node filename.ts`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just declare class in `kind` you don't actually assign it

```
class FooClass implements Foo {
    kind = 'pending' as const
    myVar: string

    constructor(text:string) {
        this.myVar = text;
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4FgBQyRyA1qACYBcyA5AA4QjmgDmNANAccgLYCeANThRqAZzBRWBAL4ECoSLEQoAQsJxdiZJtRpQAriBCsOmovyFQATGIlT8s-ATB8GaTGqgBVY+hDIAXnd0AB9PAG45fAQAGzhRUWCAYTiE5GAeOhiIHkYwRIwsPEItCkDaBiYTZHjkBD9xM15BYVtJEBYo7nqQcQMEMHQoAApIAA8wSj7WAEoNEu4iMAALYFEAOgt1IPGwSIXkR0cCGEMB4D9kGAAjfQAVdABlOw7h9GpCzx8L-zni7lEAHdgGAEMtkG91tpyH8mt14igAESVZgdRHUKAQMD6KD+AAGAHl0okUax1sgACTYdCbFpQaR4-aLYgIBHIREGIysdHITHY3HIQnE3mGYwdclUmlbawMpnEI5RAD0iuQdHa+WQhnIEBgoAg5AIPVE6Gy6xi6BYwxu9yeL0tIAggOSqVEwxokHENBm3v2BGVqvViQgYwYA31vIgon0MTAhoaJogZotVtuD2e7Ut2GhlHojFRbHYzUsug9YBo0h9USAA)